# Dynamic SOQL :System.QueryException: unexpected token: <

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I am getting the error:

> DEBUG|Query : Select Id from TestObj__c where CreatedDate <=
>   2016-07-29 00:00:00 |EXCEPTION_THROWN|[33]|System.QueryException:
>   unexpected token: < |FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: unexpected
>   token: <

```
Decimal noOfDays;
    CS_Custom_Settings__c cs = CS_Custom_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
    if(cs != null && cs.Number_of_days_Purge_Batch_Job__c != null){
        noOfDays = cs.Number_of_days_Purge_Batch_Job__c;
    }
    Date reqDate = Date.today() - Integer.valueOf(noOfDays);
    System.debug('*reqDate*'+reqDate);
    for(Purge_Batch_Job__c batchJob : Purge_Batch_Job__c.getAll().values()){
        objAPINames.add(batchJob.Object_API_Name__c);   
    }
    for(String objName : objAPINames){
        //System.debug('Query : ' + 'Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <= ' + reqDate);
        System.debug('Query : ' + 'Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <=: reqDate');
        for(sObject s : Database.Query('Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <=: reqDate')){ 
            recordIds.add((Id)s.Id);
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: DO NOT do soql queries inside a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query in for loop is correct

Use soql same in system debug as well

```
System.debug('Query : ' + 'Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <=: reqDate');
```

Here I can see you are using soql inside for loop. I  guess the above list `objAPINames` . it will contain only few sobject so it should not hit the soql governer limits

### Updates

Another issue in for loop soql, before where you need to give space

```
for(sObject s : Database.Query('Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <=: reqDate'))
```

Comment: Still the same error DEBUG|Query : Select Id from TestObj__cwhere CreatedDate <=: reqDate
EXCEPTION_THROWN|[33]|System.QueryException: unexpected token: <
|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: unexpected token: <

Comment: @wizard check my updates.. you need to give space before where

Comment: I have edited my code n I am getting date formatting issue. I am gettin DEBUG|*reqDate*2016-07-29 00:00:00 but i want it in 2016-07-29T08:00:04.000+0000 format. How can i do it

Comment: @wizard can you please ask a new question

Comment: asked http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133638/date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-t-hhmmss-sssz