# Date format yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Tags: apex, datetime

below is my code n I am getting date formatting issue. I am gettin DEBUG|*reqDate*2016-07-29 00:00:00 but i want it in 
2016-07-29T08:00:04.000+0000 format. How can i do it

```
Decimal noOfDays;
        String convDate;
        CS_Custom_Settings__c cs = CS_Custom_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
        if(cs != null && cs.Number_of_days_Purge_Batch_Job__c != null){
            noOfDays = cs.Number_of_days_Purge_Batch_Job__c;
        }
        Date reqDate = Date.today() - Integer.valueOf(noOfDays);
        System.debug('*reqDate*'+reqDate);
        for(Purge_Batch_Job__c batchJob : Purge_Batch_Job__c.getAll().values()){
            objAPINames.add(batchJob.Object_API_Name__c);   
        }
        for(String objName : objAPINames){
            //System.debug('Query : ' + 'Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <= ' + reqDate);
            System.debug('Query : ' + 'Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <=: reqDate');
            for(sObject s : Database.Query('Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <=: reqDate')){ 
                recordIds.add((Id)s.Id);
            }
```

Comment: If you need an timestamp with reqDate, reqDate should have been `DateTime` instead of `Date`.This should been `DateTime reqDate = System.now() - Integer.valueOf(noOfDays);`.

May i know,why do you want `2016-07-29T08:00:04.000+0000` this format? Is it for adding it in where clause?

Comment: what do you want to do with formatted date ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a display format issue as much as an issue with the value that your variable holds. Date variables don't have a time component. There is no 8 hours and 4 minutes associated with reqDate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Date Literals` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm?search_text=date)) instead:

```
Integer days = (Integer)cs.Number_of_days_Purge_Batch_Job__c;
String soql = 'Select Id from ' + objName + ' where CreatedDate <= LAST_N_DAYS:' + days;
```